# Bamboo Cutting board

Tags: equipment, cutting-boards

I recently purchased a bamboo cutting board and it's shedding fine splinters of wood.  Is there a way to clean this off or did I buy a bad quality board?

I've tried washing it but water doesn't seem to rinse off the fine splinters of wood very well.  In fact, the water makes the fine splinters of wood stick!

Comment: You didn't run it through the dishwasher, did you?

Comment: @Aaronut: nope, just unpackaged it and scrubbed it in the sink with a dish cloth/scrubber.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the one you got may not have been of good quality. I don't remember them being terribly expensive ($40?), so I'd take yours back. If you get a good one, it should last you for years and years, so don't be afraid to invest a little. Your new one should NOT be splintering.

And don't put your new one in the dishwasher.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just bought a cheap crappy board. Bin it and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Bamboo cutting boards get better with age.  They also have to be cured properly before use (Some don't need this).

To cure the board wipe with food grade mineral oil leaving a thin film when it gets soaked up and is dry again repeat the process.  It usually takes about a week oiling every day till it's really usable.

Maintain it by re oiling every month or so depending on how much you use it and always dry it after washing.